# Approach on control reaction(NUMBER OF LIKES) of a product without having users

Tags: mobile, ionic2

**BACKGROUND INFORMATION**

Imagine an application where the user doesn't have to sign up to actually use it. You just download the application and then you can see products and you can "react" to them.

The model for **Product** is as follows:

```
var ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  description: {type: String, required: false},
  price: {type: Number, required: true},
  company:  { type: Company.schema, required: true },
  numberOfLikes: { type: Number, required: false, default: 0},
  status: { type: ProductStatus.schema, required: true },
  image: { type: String, required: false }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Products', ProductSchema);
```

We have a functionality so the user can "react" to a product, let's say the user can LIKE a product.

But so far we don't have any email or username since people don't need to sign up. This means you could open the application on your phone and like the product a thousand times if you will, and that is not what we're aiming for. We want to avoid users to do that.

**REAL QUESTION**

Is there any information on the phone so we can take it and send it along on the Product/Reaction request so we can determine whether a person has already liked the product?

BTW:

1. We're only aiming for Android/iOS right now, web app will be for later
2. This is being developed on Ionic 2 if that helps.

Comment: Even if the "device" was identified as "unique" then how would that determine a "unique user" for a vote/like/whatever? Cannot different people use the same device? I think they can. StackOverflow thinks different people can use the same device, and is exactly why they and many others require a "log in" of some description. So it's best not to try to be "sneaky" and identify someone without asking them to identify themselves. Instead "encourage" your users to "register" and identify. Which has basically always been the solution to the problem. Don't re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make sure a product is only voted once per device using the uuid property of [cordova-plugin-device](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-device/#deviceuuid). The uuid is unique for every device. So even if a user deletes your app and reinstalls it he will not be able to rate a product again.